Power BI custom visual - Horizontal bars with curved ends
I have two measures which I want to show as horizontal overlapping bar graph with both the ends curved and white border. Something similar to the image. 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

# Sample data
    Val1 = [52]
    Val2 = [100]

# Width of the bars
    bar_width = 0.4

# Create the figure and axis
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 2))

# Plot the bars
    ax.barh(0, Val1, height=0.2, 
    color='lightblue', 
    edgecolor='white', label='Val1', alpha=0.7)
    ax.barh(0, Val2, height=0.2, color='blue', edgecolor='none', label='Val2', alpha=1)

# Add rounded corners using patches
    for bar in ax.patches:
        bar.set_linewidth(0)
        bar.set_capstyle('round')

# Add labels and formatting
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([0, Val1[0]])
    ax.set_xlim(0, Val1[0] + 100)
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')

    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

# Show plot
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


This is giving me the overlapping bars but not the curved ends. How can I get the curved ends.
The input is two values [Val1], [Val2].
